# How do I save contents in an edittext that is in a listview

Tags: java, android

In a tabbed activity, under tab 1, i have a button that adds edittexts to the screen and one each, I'd want the user to enter some text. However, when the list gets long enough, when the user opens the keyboard, it covers the list. After that when the keyboard closes all the matter typed onto the edittext gets disappeared. 
So i want to know how to take in the data typed in an edittext to an arraylist. I know we need to get gettext.tostring() but where do i type it so that it automatically gets added to the arraylist?

**have a look at this to know the issue :** https://drive.google.com/open?id=15YccHFrKYdvoxnc-ftZT9WSfcEGJG5Os

Heres what I've done:

```
public class tab1task extends Fragment {

ArrayList<String> tasks= new ArrayList<String>();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view1= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasktab1,container,false);



    Button add_task = (Button) view1.findViewById(R.id.addtask);
    add_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tasks.add("");
            ListView listView = (ListView) view1.findViewById(R.id.alltasks);

            customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();

            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
    ListView listView = (ListView) view1.findViewById(R.id.alltasks);

    customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    return view1;

}





class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.addtaskcustomlayout,null);
        EditText task = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskadd);
        task.setId(position);
        tasks.set(position,task.getText().toString());
        task.setText(tasks.get(position));



        return view;
    }



    @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return tasks.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tasks.size();
}
}

}
```

Comment: could you put some screenshot?

Comment: just look at this video to get to know the poblem. text doesnt stay . https://drive.google.com/open?id=15YccHFrKYdvoxnc-ftZT9WSfcEGJG5Os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving your value after you press the button ADD .

Try to use the code below :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.addtaskcustomlayout,null);
        EditText task = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskadd);
        task.setId(position);
        task.setText(tasks.get(position));
        TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                 tasks.set(position,s.toString());
            }
        };

        task.addTextChangedListener(tw);

        return view;
    }
```